# Calculate the covariance between two random variables

Tags: covariance

I have a random variable $x = \theta + \epsilon$ where $\theta \sim N(\mu,\alpha^{-1})$ and $\epsilon \sim N(0,\beta^{-1})$, with $Cov(\theta, \epsilon)=0$.

I want to calculate $Cov(x,\theta)$.

What I did is ($E$ denotes expected value function):

$Cov(x,\theta) = E(x\theta)-E(x)E(\theta) = E(\theta^{2}+\theta\epsilon)-\mu*\mu = \mu^{2}-0-\mu^{2} = 0$.

But I am fairly sure it is wrong. Could anyone kindly work this out?

I need this covariance to calculate the expected value and variance of the conditional process $x|\theta$.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

$$Cov(x,θ)=E(xθ)−E(x)E(θ)$$
$$=E(θ^2+θϵ)−E(x)E(θ)$$
$$=E(θ^2)+E(θ)E(ϵ)−E(x)E(θ)$$
$$=(α^{-2}+μ^2)+μ0−μ^2$$
$$=α^{-2}$$

Comment: thanks, I don't get from where the $\mu_0$ comes from?

Comment: It's just $E(θ) \times E(ϵ) = \mu \times 0 = 0$.

Comment: I think your answer is wrong. From where does the first $\mu^2$ come from?

Comment: $E(θ^2)=Var(θ)+(E(θ))^2=(α^{−2}+μ^2)$